# Bookmarklet javascript popup trouble

Tags: javascript, browser

Sorry to add to the burgeoning noise on bookmarklets. I'm having trouble figuring out the right approach and some trouble coding it.

When the bookmarklet is activated, I want to

1) Open a popup as about:blank
2) Then change the URL to my external web page which handles the functionality of the bookmarklet
3) And in the process pass parameters to that page in the GET request

It should be easy right? Then why does #1 insist opening a new tab in Chrome rather than a popup?

```
<a href="javascript:(function(x) {var mypop=window.open('about:blank',config='height=200,width=400,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');})('hello world');" >Click</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the second parameter to `window.open()`, so your config string is being interpreted as window name, not settings. Use this:

```
window.open('about:blank', '_blank', '... your parameters ...');
```